# If I break up a large table so it doesn't overflow onto the next page how do I suppress the numbering

Tags: tables, captions

I have a long table that overflows one page.
If I break up the table into two tables, how do I suppress the numbering so that I only get one figure count advancement and not two.

This is slightly different from the post marked as identical in that this applies to tables and not figures, but the solutions are exactly identical.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you looked into using the `caption` package and its `\ContinuedFloat` macro? Do check out pp. 21-23 of the package's user guide.

Comment: May I advise using `longtable` or `longtabu`, which both provide tables that are splittable over pages.

Comment: Thanks - that is insane! I used the caption package with \ContinuedFloat (case sensitive btw) and I get the same numbering. Works like a champ.

Comment: @MichaelFraiman I would not advise using `longtabu` or `tabu` under any circumstances short of threat of death or an extremely large bribe. I recognise some like to live dangerously, but even so. `longtable` doesn't float, so it is not a good option if you want your table to float.

Comment: @Mico An answer ? Or is this a duplicate?

Comment: I will accept micro's answer. I read up on longtable, and it didn't seem as straight forward as caption and \ContinuedFloat

Comment: @cfr - I think I found an earlier posting on `\ContinuedFloat`.

Comment: @cfr: I do accord and only want to note: if the OP would use `longtable` he simply could use `\caption{Table title}` in the `\endfirsthead` section to have a numbered title with entry to the list of tables for the first table page and, e.g., `\caption[]{Table title (continued)}` in the `\endhead` section to have numbered titles without entry to the list of tables on all other pages.

Comment: @cfr I have heard there are some bugs in `tabu`, but AFAIK it is compatable with booktabs and it works quite OK for me.

Comment: @MichaelFraiman The author has promised a backwards-incompatible update. Meanwhile, serious bugs will not be fixed. At some point, all current code will break. That's not OK for me and it should not be recommended to others without a warning that their code will break at some point with no backwards-compatibility option available. That will mean rewriting every table which uses `tabu` in order to recompile, or downgrading. Neither are straightforward for most users. Neither will be good news in the face of an imminent deadline.

Comment: @cfr thanks for warning. Switching back to `tabularx`.

Comment: Hi guys, This isn't quite working for me 100%. my 2nd table has the first label as the first, but the 3rd independent table now starts as Table 3 instead of Table 2. So I have Table 1 and Table  3 and the continued Float one takes up a counter in the table of contents and in references in the paper.

Comment: OK - fixed it. I broke it by doing this \begin{table}
\ContinuedFloat
\caption[]{Meshing    I was able to fix it by removing the brackets after the word caption